# Is casting from MyObject[] to Object[] and then back again a bad code smell?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I'm reviewing/refactoring some code and I met an interdependency I don't like, but I'm not sure what the best way to fix this in C# is. The essence of my question is that in one file I have:

```
class MyObject
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int? Age {get;set;}
}

public interface IConnection
{
  void Connect(string user,string pw,Action<MyObject[]> onConnect);
  void Disconnect();
}
```

Then in another file:

```
public class ConcreteDataProvider : IConnection
{
  public void Connect(string user,string pw,Action<MyObject[]> onConnect)
  {
    //...
    IEnumerable<MyObject> collection = ...
    onConnect( collection.ToArray() );
  }
}
```

The issue I have with this design is that `MyObject` is specific to this concrete data provider. I don't want it mentioned in `IConnection`.

My idea was to refactor `IConnection.Connect()` to look like:

```
void Connect(string user,string pw,Action<Object[]> onConnect);
```

And then in the `ConcreteDataProvider` implementation of `onConnect` I will cast the array to `MyObject[]`.
(By the looks of [Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to 'MyObject[]', what gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212429/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-object-to-myobject-what-gives) that means I will need to use `Array.ConvertAll`)

Is this a bad design that will come back to haunt me?

---

BTW, the call to `ToArray()` triggers the data download, and I don't want `onConnect()` called until it finishes. Behind the scenes it also triggers the actual connection; I don't know if the connection is valid and working until a first query has been performed. Which is why I don't want to pass `IEnumerable` to `OnConnect()`, and have it do the call to `ToArray()`.

Comment: Are `IConnection` and `IDataProvider` different interfaces?

Comment: @Rawling Sorry, no, that was a typo. I just fixed the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using generics?

```
public interface IConnection<T>
{
  void Connect(string user, string pw, Action<T[]> onConnect);
  void Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What are the pros/cons of this, over Object[]?

Comment: Strong typing, compile-time safety, refactor friendly, no need to perform casts at runtime, ... this list goes on.

Comment: That is a good list of good points. The big downside to this is the difficulty I had getting it to compile! First I needed a new constraint on the MyObject class. Then the LINQ intelligence failed, and wanted me to specify the template parameters explicitly on the select call (CS0411).